# Extract elements from list of lists

Tags: python

I have an object and I want to extract some elements from object to made a list.

I have this

```
[["Test_1", 
  {"name": "Test_level_1", "value": 10}, 
  {"name": "Test_level_1 again", "value": 15}], 
 ["Test_2", 
  {"name": "Test_level_2", "value": 1}, 
  {"name": "Test_level_2 again", "value": 5}]]
```

And I trying to have this

```
["Test_level_1", 
 "Test_level_1 again", 
 "Test_level_2", 
 "Test_level_2 again"]
```

What is the way to do it?

Comment: Do you currently have Python code you've tried to write?

Comment: Hi, I rolled back your latest edit because that's a separate question. You can [ask a new question](/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension will cover this quite nicely.

```
data = [["Test_1", 
  {"name": "Test_level_1", "value": 10}, 
  {"name": "Test_level_1 again", "value": 15}], 
 ["Test_2", 
  {"name": "Test_level_2", "value": 1}, 
  {"name": "Test_level_2 again", "value": 5}]]

desired_data = [item['name'] for sublist in data 
                             for item in sublist 
                             if isinstance(item, dict)]
```

Result:

```
['Test_level_1', 'Test_level_1 again', 'Test_level_2', 'Test_level_2 again']
```

Comment: According to the structure in the question, one can also do `for item in sublist[1:]` and remove the if...

Comment: Quite right. I decided to not make that assumption, but if the data can be guaranteed to follow that form, that is nicer.

Comment: Thanks @Chris

I would like to update the list, so it could look like this `[["Test_1", {"name": "Test_level_1", "value": 10}, {"name": "Test_level_1 again", "value": 15}, 15 (the max value), 1 (the position of the max value in the list)], ["Test_2", {"name": "Test_level_2", "value": 1}, {"name": "Test_level_2 again", "value": 5}, 15 (the max value), 1 (the position of the max value in the list)], ["Total", 11, 20, 20 (the max value), 1 (the position of the max value in the list)]]`

Comment: Well, to put you on the right track, you could get the max value with `max` and a generator expression.  `max(item["value"] for sublist in data for item in sublist if isinstance(item, dict))`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your list, with a nice unpacking and keep the value from `"name"`

```
values = [["Test_1", {"name":"Test_level_1", "value":10}, {"name":"Test_level_1 again", "value":15}], 
          ["Test_2", {"name":"Test_level_2", "value":1}, {"name":"Test_level_2 again", "value":5}]]

result = []
for first, *others in values:
    for other in others:
        result.append(other["name"])
```

Comment: Without two iteration, is it a way to solve it ? Cuz I did it like that

Comment: @alexis You need a loop over each list within the outer list, so no

Answer (score -2):

```
arr = [
  ["Test_1",
   {"name": "Test_level_1",
    "value": 10},
   {"name": "Test_level_1 again",
    "value": 15}],
  ["Test_2",
   {"name": "Test_level_2",
    "value": 1},
   {"name": "Test_level_2 again",
    "value": 5}]
]

ans = [item["name"] for subarr in arr 
                    for index, item in enumerate(subarr) 
                    if index!=0]
print(ans)
```

Comment: Instead of checking all indexes are not equal to zero you can just slice the list... `for item in subarr[1:]`